Кнопка назад webapp telegram не корректно отрабатывает в angular 17
Делаю на 17 версии ангуляра Telegram Mini Apps.
Есть главная страница tasks со списком тасков, и страница task с подробным описанием таска.
C главной страницы с помощью this.router.navigate(["/task", taskId] открываем страницу task , там по полученому id подгружаем таску. И с этой страницы нужно вернуться на главную
Написал функцию, кинул кнопку в шаблон, дергаю функцию по клику, и все работает хорошо, ngOnInit вызывается каждый переход назад на странице tasks
public back(): void {
    this.router.navigate([""]);
}

Но воспользовавшись кнопкой назад телеграма, моя страница tasks оказывается пустой. Причем на desktop telegram она просто пустая, и как будто циклы в шаблоне не отработали, а на андройде можно попробовать проскролить пустую страницу, и тут же появляется контент.
Код кнопки
window.Telegram.WebApp.BackButton.onClick(() => this.router.navigate([""]))

Не вызывается ngOnInit, но роут встает правильный. В общем обычная кнопка назад, и телеграмовская вызывают одну и ту же функцию, только обычная работает, а телеграмовская нет

Вообще в целом при маршрутизации с кнопок телеграма (SettingsButton, BackButton), на компонентах не вызывается ngOnInit, хотя ngOnDestroy работает.
